# Convert pandas str column to float without loss of precision

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

im receiving this data from an API which in turn I put into a dataFrame object. everything works fine until I need to change some of the columns into float from their original str format. after using pd.to_numeric and pd.astype(float) and .apply(float) I saw that my data Is limited at 5-6 digits after the floating-point. here is the before:

```
               Price        Weight
Ticker                                
A         2.5280000000  0.1107699174
B       137.6500000000  0.0315685242
C       203.0600000000  0.1220829996
D         5.6920000000  0.0406895407
```

and here is after:

```
            Price    Weight
Ticker                       
A         2.52800  0.110770
B       137.65000  0.031569
C       203.06000  0.122083
D         5.69200  0.040690
```

although 6 digits is good, i need the entire data to perform percise calculations for model-making purposes. i would truly appreciate any help on this!

Comment: Do you have evidence that you're losing precision (as compared to just truncating for sake of printing)? I doubt it given the core of pandas being written in C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `pandas` *shows* 6 digits after `.`, but that does not imply precision of stored value, if value is stored with enough precision then it should be enough to set `pandas.options.display.precision` value to greater value to see it, consider following example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[0.1107699174]})
print(df)
pd.options.display.precision = 12
print(df)
```

output

```
         x
0  0.11077
              x
0  0.1107699174
```